# Unable to use maven in Eclipse IDE

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I am trying to create Maven project in my eclipse IDE after choosing File->new->other->Maven Project-> maven-archetype-quickstart version 1.1 and i am getting this error

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archtypes:maven-archtype-quickstart1:1 from any of the configured repositories.

I tried many methods but the error still exist. I also uninstalled eclipse and installed couple times and this error is still existing. Can someone help me out in this situation.

Following is my error trace

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Probably a network/firewall issue.

Comment: Which JDK version do you use? ` sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: un?  ?

Comment: JDK version is JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a proxy issue, you might want to try a couple of things:

- Add the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml as a *remote catalog*. When you are in the archetype step in the **New Maven Project window**, select **Configure...**->**Add Remote Catalog...**, paste the URL, and give it a name.
- Delete your local Maven repository which, by default, is in the `.m2` directory of your user home directory.

If you are using a proxy, you can configure it in the preferences (**General**->**Network Connections**).

Comment: I tried your steps. But the error is still continuing . After i added a remote catalog it is not showing any artifact there. I have to choose All catalog in the catalog files in order to choose any thing and eventually to click next. May i know what should i do in Network connection. At this moment it says Native in Active Provider field.